# How to fill a glm::vec3 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I've got three vectors which represent each cordinate in a *x, y, z* system. What I want to do is to create a `glm::vec3` in order to join each component of every point like this for example:

`x[0] = 1, y[0] = 0, z[0] = 2 -> new_vector[0] = (1, 0, 2)`

My code so far is this one:

```
glm::vec3 transform(std::vector<float> const& test)
{
    std::vector<float> mul_x (test.size());
    std::vector<float> mul_y (test.size());
    std::vector<float> mul_z (test.size());
    glm::vec3 new_vector;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
    {
        mul_x[i] = test[i]*lib::x[i];
        mul_y[i] = test[i]*lib::y[i];   
        mul_z[i] = test[i]*lib::z[i];           
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
    {
        new_vector[i].x = mul_x[i]; 
        new_vector[i].y = mul_y[i]; 
        new_vector[i].z = mul_z[i];
    }

return new_vector;

}
```

Where `lib::x`, `lib::y` and `lib::z` are three pre-defined `std::vector<float>`.

But compiler returns to me an error message. Particularly this one:

`error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘new_vector.glm::tvec3<T, P>::operator[]<float, (glm::precision)0u>(i)’, which is of non-class type ‘float’ new_vector[i].x = mul_x[i];`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that new_vector must also be an `std::vector`, otherwise you are trying to pack `test.size()` vectors into a single one. The reason you might be confused is that `glm::vec3`'s `operator []` actually refers to the *x, y, z* components, not to individual vectors. Replace your `glm::vec3` with `std::vector<glm:::vec3>` and you should be fine.

Comment: Also I advise you have a look at how you could optimise that function, as there are a few things you could do to make it faster.

Comment: but if I change the type it will mismatch the return type, because my function needs to return a `glm::vec3`, not a `std::vector<glm::vec3>`

Comment: Should this function take a series of points, and output one point?

Comment: this function should take a series of coordinates *x, y, z* and output a series of points